# How to disable (RFT-DCA) security prompts in Office 2003

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, file-conversion, office-2003

I am currently converting rft-dca files into a readable file format using a Visual Basic Script in Office 2003 since it is the last Office version to natively support rft-dca files.
However everytime a rft-dca file is being opened I do get a security prompt warning related to rft-dca files.
Since it's more than 200000 files I can not click yes on every file.
Is there an option to disable even all security warnings under Office 2003?

Inside Offices 2003 Security options I set everything related to scripts etc. to off or the lowest setting.
Created a "Security" reg-key set to 1.
Went through Office 2003 group policies and set eveything related to scripts to off/deactivated.
Nothing prevented the security prompt.

Comment: I don't know how to disable those messages but you could see if this converter is still available (I'm at work, can't try it)
https://microsoft.public.word.docmanagement.narkive.com/DleKOCcQ/how-can-i-convert-a-displaywrite-file-to-microsoft-word

Comment: Maybe try https://mendelson.org/legacyfileconverter.html (I haven't, but the tool converts to RTF and I doubt that the RFT-DCA converter in the 2003 version adds much, if any, functionality.

Comment: What have you tried in VBA (for example: Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone)?